Правильно поставлена запятая в предложении с предлогом "кроме"?
Предложение с другого сайта:
Деньги кроме всякой вредности, помогают при бедности.
Нужна ли запятая? Тако впечатление, что это запись по слуху.
Это включение или исключение, какое нужно применить правило?

Возможно, вы правы) Но какой вариант  оформления предложения вы считаете правильным, запишите, пожалуйста,  в поле ответа.  Ну и каким правилом вы пользуетесь в этой теме? В справочниках Розенталя и ПАС  мнения не совсем совпадают, да и практика письма вносит свои коррективы.

Шарон, ну вы же сами знаете, что сегодня предлог кроме выделяется запятыми во всех значениях.

Серж, рекомендуется выделять, я так это понимаю.  Но однозначность практически всегда нехороша, а  у нас это часто приветствуется – по таким правилам легче живется.  В действительности (и это видно на практике) многое зависит от грамматической структуры предложения. Различать семантику оборотов НУЖНО, так как обособление при исключении более частотно. Нам важно подчеркнуть значимость такого оборота.

Sharon, если практика письма показывает, что эти обороты выделяют в независимости от значения, в чем проблема? Старые правила никто не отменял. Обособляйте, если считаете нужным. На все воля автора.

На все воля автора?  Как сказать!  Не стоит бросаться в крайности: то жесткая регламентация, то вседозволенность.  Хотелось бы видеть разумные решения.  В том числе в заданном предложении.

Sharon, разумное решение — это правила- 56.

Серж,  приведите пжста ваш вариант разумного решения для заданного предложения, только и всего.  Пусть вы, к примеру, автор. По вашему мнению,  на все воля автора, так ведь надо понимать правила?  А то в теме 4 человека, но только один ответ, которым не все довольны.  Ответа на комментарий тоже нет.  Если в записи с одной запятой ошибка, то почему люди так пишут? Может,  одну паузу слышат?  Или как вы думаете?

Или "деньги, кроме вредности, помогают при бедности" или "деньги кроме бедности помогают при бедности".

Только два варианта: с запятой и без.

Предлагаю следующий вариант:
Деньги кроме всякой вредности помогают при бедности.
Оборот с предлогом «кроме» не выделяется запятой, если является дополнением в предложении. Предлог имеет значение включения «помимо», «дополнительно», «вдобавок». Ссылка на правило
Мне кажется, что речь идет о свойствах предмета. Несмотря, на то, что вред и польза противоположны по смыслу, тем не менее они являются свойствами денег. Значит, используется значение включения. К каким-то "плохим" свойствам добавляется "хорошее".
Но и предложенный вариант допустим, при таком значении предлога. Ссылка

Вы правильно определили значение включения, интересное решение, поэтому я приму ответ. // Я для себя в этой теме придумала формальное правило и пользуюсь им, но вот наши решения совпали. // В правилах ПАС говорится:  В настоящее время различия в значениях оборотов со словом кроме не сказываются на пунктуации: и в том и в другом случае предусмотрено выделение запятыми. //Я считаю, что предусмотрено, да необязательно, то есть возможны варианты без обособления.

Думаю, что решение здесь факультативное, как и для обстоятельств, то есть зависит от степени распространенности оборота,  позиции в предложении и т.д. // Но вот в тексте в похожем предложении оборот обособлен:  Деньги, кроме всякой вредности,
Хорошо помогают от бедности. Вы можете согласиться с таким решением?   https://stihi.ru/2014/06/06/3897

@Дмитрий Из вашего ответа: Но и предложенный вариант допустим... Я думаю, что вариант с одной запятой никак не может быть верным.

Вероятно, Дмитрий имел в виду " обособление оборота допустимо", что  именно так.  Но если возникают вопросы об одной запятой, то зачем ее здесь НЕПРАВИЛЬНО поставили?

Возможно, я не правильно мыслю, даже, скорее всего, так и есть. Но мне кажется, можно и одну запятую поставить. Если оборот не обособлять, то предложение должно произносить ровным и спокойном тоном. (Об этом говорится в тексте по первой ссылке). Тогда получается, что в нашем случае запятые можно использовать для придания желаемой интонации. А она действительно может быть разной в зависимости от контекста.

@РиммаМихайлова, поясните пожалуйста почему вы считаете "что вариант с одной запятой никак не может быть верным." ?

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Мне неясны комментарии участников. Не нравится принятый ответ? Дайте свой альтернативный вариант (в ответе или хотя бы в комментариях), не стоит ограничиваться одним предложением: это не может быть верным и т.д.

Вот заданный вопрос:
Это включение или исключение, какое нужно применить правило?



Правило и вариант ответа предоставлены, семантика (включение или исключение) определена верно. Что же еще надо?

Ах да, а почему такая странная запись (одна запятая) в предложенном варианте? Есть ли в ней какой-либо смысл? Может, по слуху записана? На этот вопрос никто правильно не ответил. А тогда зачем критиковать?

Предлог "кроме" выделяется теперь запятыми во всех значениях? Есть такая притча о Буридановом осле, очень любопытная, вот одно из толкований: https://proza.ru/2021/05/03/1620


Теперь пользователи вообще не могут решить задачу. Получается так:
 Или "деньги, кроме вредности, помогают при бедности" или 
 "деньги кроме бедности помогают при бедности". Только два 
  варианта: с запятой и без. 

А где решение? Я не могу записать оба варианта, мне нужен один.

Честно говоря, я собиралась  дать свой ответ со всеми объяснениями, а потом раздумала. Я часто так делаю, а зачем? Ничего не меняется...

Предлагаю продолжить обсуждение. Тому, кто даст полный ответ, я вроде бы (по правилам) могу дать конкурсную премию сразу?
Я не могу записать два варианта сразу, поэтому нужен один
вариант. Тот, который лучше, с вашей точки зрения. Нет однозначного ответа – нет решения.  //  Были еще темы в вопросе:  (1) Почему ставят одну запятую?  (2) Это включение или исключение и почему? (3) Семантику вообще не надо учитывать и даже определять или все-таки нужно?
